# Finding symbolic series coefficients

Tags: symbolic, series-expansion

Is there any way to get the symbolic form of a series?  For simple series this seems possible e.g. 
`SeriesCoefficent[Exp[x],{x,0,n}]`
tells me that the general series coefficient is `1/n`!
However even marginally more complicated series such as `(1+x^(1/2))^(2/3)` fail with this input.  Asymptotic series e.g. `Series[BesselJ[n,x],{x,DirectedInfinty[1],m}]` fail completely.

*Mathematica* must *know* these things: it calculates them quickly enough.  However, I can not figure out how to get it to *tell* me these things.

Comment: Did you use `SeriesCoefficient` rather than `Series`?

Comment: Yes, Sorry.  SeriesCoefficient,

Comment: When I try: SeriesCoefficient[BesselJ[7, x], {x, 0, n}] (or replace the 7 by any number) it seems to work fine. You might want to check that having the same variable n inside the Bessel function and as the limit of the {x,0,n} is what you really want.

Comment: Actually, that does get you an answer.  Not only is there no indication of the leading asymptotic behavior, but (as far as I can see) the answer given is simply wrong.  Nor do I understand why "7" has to be a number.  DLMF gives a form general for all orders of both the asymptotic expansion and the bessel function.